How to select and unselect all checkboxes based on button click in flutter
I have a listview which contains checkbox inside the listTile. This listTile will be generated dynamically based on the length of the list. Here is my ListTile and Custom checkbox code.
   ListTile(
        leading: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 42,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                        "assets/images/ic_subtract.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            child: const Image(
            image: AssetImage(
                "assets/images/ic_dummy_project_icon.png"),
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            )),
        title: Text(
            eventTicketList[index]
                .firstName
                .toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(
                    26, 49, 60, 1),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text')),
        subtitle: loadTicketInfo(
            eventTicketList, index),
        trailing: loadCheckBox(isChecked))

 loadCheckBox(bool isChecked) {
    return CustomCheckbox(
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        })
      },
    );

class CustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCheckbox({
    required this.value,
    Key? key,
    this.width = 24.0,
    this.height = 24.0,
    this.color,
    this.iconSize,
    this.onChanged,
    this.checkColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color? color;
  final bool? value;
  // Now you can set the checkmark size of your own
  final double? iconSize;
  final Color? checkColor;
  final Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  @override
  State<CustomCheckbox> createState() => _CustomCheckboxState();
}

class _CustomCheckboxState extends State<CustomCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => isChecked = !isChecked);
        widget.onChanged?.call(isChecked);
      },
      child: Container(
          width: widget.width,
          height: widget.height,
          child: isChecked
              ? Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_checked.png"),
            height: 24,
            width: 24,
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          )
              : Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/ic_selector.png"),
            height: 24,
            width: 24,
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

I want to select all the check box when i click the button and I also want to unselect all when I click the same button again. I have tried few examples from stackoverflow and from different other sources. But nothing works fine or I have not done that properly. Could someone help me to solve this problem?
 Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25),
    child: TextButton(
        child: const Text("Select All",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(
                    0, 94, 180, 1))),
        onPressed: () {
          //select all checkbox
        }))


All you need to do is to override didUpdateWidget inside CustomCheckbox widget. Because CustomCheckBox widget is stateful widget, you don't get it's initState called multiple times to set isChecked. DidUpdateWidget gets called followed by build method.
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant CustomCheckbox oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
      isChecked = widget.value!;
    }
  }

Here is the full code which I tried
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _isAllChecked = false;

  final List<String> _items = const [
    'London',
    'Paris',
    'New York',
    'Berlin',
    'Madrid'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Checkboxes'),
        actions: [
          Checkbox.adaptive(
              value: _isAllChecked,
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return;
                }
                setState(() {
                  _isAllChecked = value;
                });
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                _items[index],
              ),
              trailing: loadCheckBox(_isAllChecked));
        },
        itemCount: _items.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  loadCheckBox(bool isChecked) {
    return CustomCheckbox(
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCheckbox({
    required this.value,
    super.key,
    this.width = 24.0,
    this.height = 24.0,
    this.color,
    this.iconSize,
    this.onChanged,
    this.checkColor,
  });

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color? color;
  final bool? value;
  // Now you can set the checkmark size of your own
  final double? iconSize;
  final Color? checkColor;
  final Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  @override
  State<CustomCheckbox> createState() => _CustomCheckboxState();
}

class _CustomCheckboxState extends State<CustomCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() => isChecked = !isChecked);
        widget.onChanged?.call(isChecked);
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: widget.width,
        height: widget.height,
        child: isChecked
            ? const Icon(Icons.check_box)
            : const Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant CustomCheckbox oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
      isChecked = widget.value!;
    }
  }
}

